# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup Incremental not found

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-backups

Trying to backup SQL SErver 2008 R2 database using Powershell scripts. The full backup and log backup scripts are working fine. Now I got an error when trying to do incremental.

```
$backup = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup
echo $backup
$backpup.Incremental = $TRUE
```

Here is output:

```
Action                      : Database
BackupSetDescription        : 
BackupSetName               : 
ExpirationDate              : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
FormatMedia                 : False
Initialize                  : False
MediaDescription            : 
RetainDays                  : -1
SkipTapeHeader              : False
LogTruncation               : Truncate
CopyOnly                    : False
Incremental                 : False
Mirrors                     : {Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceList, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceList, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceList}
UndoFileName                : 
CompressionOption           : Default
BlockSize                   : -1
BufferCount                 : -1
MaxTransferSize             : -1
AsyncStatus                 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AsyncStatus
Devices                     : {}
DatabaseFiles               : {}
DatabaseFileGroups          : {}
Database                    : 
Checksum                    : False
ContinueAfterError          : False
MediaName                   : 
NoRewind                    : False
PercentCompleteNotification : 10
Restart                     : False
UnloadTapeAfter             : False
NoRecovery                  : False

The property 'Incremental' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:3 char:2
+  $backpup.Incremental = $TRUE
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

I have no clue about that and google can't find any similar cases.

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this may assist: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.incremental.aspx`